# What are other ways to say that I'm no match for someone?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am looking for idiomatic sentences to say that "I am nowhere near someone's level" similar to "I'm no match for (someone)".

Comment: You're **out of their league**.

Comment: To be specfic, are you talking about their level in chess? boxing? beauty? or something else?

Comment: @James K yes, a skill, something they worked on for a long time.

Comment: Note that "out of someone's league" is not symmetric. "You're out of my league" means you're better at something, while "I'm out of your league" means I'm better.

Comment: They have me outclassed.

Comment: I can't hold a candle to them.